# Ordered list using thymeleaf loop not connected

Tags: java, html, web, thymeleaf, html-lists

I'm sorry if I have to be vague as I can't really show the clients requirement.

I have a stacked ordered list, which shows details of the parent and child. Before the parent and child part, the first item and more item after the parent-child part is showing different details, but I have to put it in the same list. So what I'm trying to achieve is:

[image]

But what I got:

[image]

```
<ol type="a">
  <li>Coffee</li> //item without child detail

  <span class="widget-has-slot">{{the parent-child widget}}<br />
  <pre>
 &lt;li th:each="parent : ${parentChildMap}"&gt; //parent

   //parent detail

  &lt;ol&gt;                                   //child list start
   &lt;li th:each="child : ${parent.value}"&gt; //child

   //child detail

   &lt;/li&gt;                                  //child closing tag
  &lt;/ol&gt;                                  //child list end
 &lt;/li&gt;                                  //parent closing tag

<li>Water</li>  //more item without child detail
<li>Beer</li>
</ol>
```

I tried using counter increment, but it still showing the same result.
Reference:

1. https://travishorn.com/ordered-lists-in-html-a4621e17532b
2. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_counter-increment.php#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=list

Currently, I'm using 3 different ol with start value. One for the first item, one for the thymeleaf part, and another one after the thymeleaf, which shows me the result I wanted, but I know this is not efficient as I will need to change the start value when the number of parent changed.

```
<ol type="a">     // first ol
  <li>Coffee</li> //item without child detail
</ol>

  <span class="widget-has-slot">{{the parent-child widget}}<br />
  <pre>
&lt;ol type="a" start="2"&gt;                    //second ol
 &lt;li th:each="parent : ${parentChildMap}"&gt; //parent

   //parent detail

  &lt;ol&gt;                                   //child list start
   &lt;li th:each="child : ${parent.value}"&gt; //child

   //child detail

   &lt;/li&gt;                                  //child closing tag
  &lt;/ol&gt;                                  //child list end
 &lt;/li&gt;                                  //parent closing tag
&lt;/ol&gt; 

<ol type="a" start="5">   //third ol
 <li>Water</li>  //more item without child detail
 <li>Beer</li>
</ol>
```

How do I get them to work without manually changing start values?

Answer (score 1):

Use `th:start`, and calculate the start dynamically.

```
<ol type="a" th:start="${2 + #lists.size(parentChildMap)}">
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but only the parent-child ol is inside the widget, so the first and third ol is normal html. I don't think I can turn the other list into thymeleaf.

Comment: Thymeleaf doesn't have the concept of a "widget"... so I'm not really sure what you mean.  Why are you restricted to normal html in the other two parts?

Comment: the client and most of the team somehow refer to the thymeleaf parts as widget, sorry I got affected and used that here. The page we're working on is to generate a pdf report where the user could edit the template, and we used html as the template.